# Conflict using file.available() to show progress of in.readObject() reading one large Object

Tags: java

I have a single large Object (about 20MB) I sometimes write to or read from disk.  There are no problems doing this and waiting for completion but it takes about a minute and I like to show whats happening using a progress bar.

My read code is as follows:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);

// start a thread using file.available() to update a progress bar...
InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);           
site = (Site) in.readObject();
in.close(); 
buffer.close();
file.close();
```

It all works fine so long as I don't call `file.available()` continuously without pause.  It would seem that calling `file.available()` while `in.readObject()` is active can sometimes cause a conflict.  Putting in a delay seems a foolish fudge.  Please can someone tell me the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a byte counting InputStream.  This can tell you how much data has been read and you can compare this with the actual file size to get a progress.

Perhaps you could explain why file.available() doesn't work.  What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, silly of me not to say..  in.readObject(): invalid type code: 00

Comment: Thank you.  in.readObject generates the exception  invalid type code: 00

Answer (score 0):

Use Java NIO to non-blocking reads/writes, look at examples : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/FileChannel.htm

Comment: Really? With `ObjectINputStream`. Seems a little overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by conflict?

Obviously busy waiting is not going to be great for performance. Calling `FileInputStream.available` continuously may acquire a lock (implementation dependent), which may not be released in a fair manner.

In any case, [`available`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available%28%29) is the wrong method. It only returning an estimate of the number of bytes available *without blocking*. Instead, add a metering decorator between the `BufferedInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` (between `FileInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` should be sufficiently accurate and faster. The decorator should just record the number of bytes available. Periodically (use `javax.swing.Timer` (not `java.util`!) in Swing (or AWT)) update the display.

Comment: Thank you. in.readObject generates the exception invalid type code: 00

Answer (score 0):

In [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available%28%29) is stated that "In some cases, a non-blocking read (or skip) may appear to be blocked when it is merely slow, for example when reading large files over slow networks. "

In had a similar situation when writing a file and  wanted to know how much bytes i had stored. I implemented my own OutputStream and added a byte counter var and a getBytesRead() method. Then another thread was calling the getBytesRead() and updated my progress bar. Ofcourse in order to do this you need to know how large the file is ( in order to calculate the prercentage). Hopefully you can write something analogous with the inputStream

```
public class CountingOutputStream extends BufferedOutputStream{
private long bytesRead = 0;

public CountingOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
    super(out);
}

@Override
public synchronized void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
        throws IOException {
    super.write(b, off, len);
    bytesRead += len;
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    super.write(b);
    bytesRead += b.length;
}

@Override
public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
    super.write(b);
    bytesRead++;
}

public long getBytesRead() {
    return bytesRead;
}

}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach though!
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure while `FileInputStream.available()` is not working, but my guess is that the methods that you are using from 2 different threads are not threadsafe.

The solution is to create a thread-safe wrapper for your FileInputStream that keeps a count of the bytes read, and exposes it via a thread-safe getter method that the monitoring thread can access.